# kontakt exchange for post audio

Tags: sound-design

anyone interested in exchanging kontakt instruments they've made?
I'm starting to build more and more foley stuff as i see fit. 
It saves a lot of time using a controller VS pro tools chops

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this does not appear to be a question.  We do sometimes (rarely) support exchange questions like this, but they need to be more focused around a particular kind of sound, not just leaving it open for anything goes.